# view files are not rendered in zend framework

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework

With below code i have set layout and view files path.

```
 class DemoMet_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $theme = 'metronic_v3';
        $layout_name = 'default';

        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();

        $layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'themes'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $theme . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'layouts'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'scripts'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $layout->setLayoutPath($layoutPath);
        $layout->setLayout($layout_name);

        $viewPath = APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'themes'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $theme . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'views'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $layout->getView()->setBasePath($viewPath);

    }


}
```

but when I access the url "http://project.localhost/demoMet/index/" .
Error message

> with message 'script 'index/index.phtml' not found in path
>   project/application/modules/demoMet/views/scripts/

Though the view files path is set but it searching in default script folder

Comment: In bootstrap under which function this to be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a _init function to your main application Bootatrp.php file!

**Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    //Bootstrap view 
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    //get bootstrapped view
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/templates/default/views/scripts");
    //$view->addScriptPath($theme);
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/templates/default/views/helpers/", "Administration_View_Helper");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $theme = 'metronic_v3';
    $layout_name = 'default';

    // without the last DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    $layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'themes'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $theme . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'layouts'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'scripts';

    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout($layout_name);
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayoutPath($layoutPath);

    // with add 'scripts' after the last DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    $viewPath = APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'themes'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $theme . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'views'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'scripts';

    $this->view->setBasePath($viewPath);
}
```